# react does not re-render on context change

Tags: reactjs

I create a context, use context in consumer, after update, the interface is not re-rendering. Please help.

The reason that I am not using state is because the `Sample1` will have to pass down the component tree and it will be hard to maintain.

Another problem I am having is at `onChange={updateContext}`. Is there a way to pass in some parameters into the `updateContext` so that it knows which question and answer to be updated?

```
// Dependencies
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

// CSS
import './App.css';

// API
import Sample1 from "./api/Sample1";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

function updateContext() {
    console.log(Sample1);
    Sample1.Questions[0].Answers[0].Selected = !Sample1.Questions[0].Answers[0].Selected;
}

function Selection(props) {
    const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
    return (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
            {() => (
                <FormGroup row>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox checked={userContext.Questions[0].Answers[0].Selected} onChange={updateContext} name="Answers0" />}
                        label={userContext.Questions[0].Answers[0].Answer}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
            )}
        </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
}

function App(props) {
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={Sample1}>
            <Selection>

            </Selection>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your are updating state will not re-render component. Please try below solution.

```
const { useContext, setContext   } = useContext(UserContext);
```

And while updating..

```
function updateContext() {

   setContext('New Value Here')// new Logic : Update whatever your context value is
    console.log(Sample1);
    Sample1.Questions[0].Answers[0].Selected = !Sample1.Questions[0].Answers[0].Selected;
}
```